# Оптимизация кода работы с Таблицей Гугл

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Имеются 10 листов, в которых происходит то самое действие.

Как можно оптимизировать код, чтобы не писать этот код для каждого листа, с выводом результата в свой лист?

```
function onEdit(е) {

  var statusIn = "REQUEST IN PROCESS";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var sen = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").getValue();

  var rasa = sen.length;

  var bar_r1 = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("F5").getValue();

  var re1 = bar_r1.length;

  var bar_r = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B5").getValue();

  var re = bar_r.length;

  var bar_r2 = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("J5").getValue();

  var re2 = bar_r2.length;

  var bar_r3 = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("N5").getValue();

  var re3 = bar_r3.length;

  if (re > rasa) {
    ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

  if (re2 > rasa) {
    ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

  if (re1 > rasa) {
    ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

  if (re3 > rasa) {
    ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }



  // Следующий лист 

  var senr = ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("B2").getValue();
  var rasar = senr.length;

  var bar_rr = ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("B5").getValue();
  var rer = bar_rr.length;
  var bar_r1r = ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("F5").getValue();
  var re1r = bar_r1r.length;
  var bar_r2r = ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("J5").getValue();
  var re2r = bar_r2r.length;
  var bar_r3r = ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("N5").getValue();
  var re3r = bar_r3r.length;

  if (rer > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

  if (re1r > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

  if (re2r > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

  if (re3r > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(rozp).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }

}
```

По ответу уважаемого 'oshliaer' пробовал подписать код для следующей фикции но при выполнении всё работает, только во всех листах одновременно, а не в том в котором была нажата кнопка с функцией.

```
"use strict";
function finish() {
  try{
    var statusFin = "REQUEST FINISH";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var each = function(){
      return function(tabl){
        go(ss, tabl, statusFin);
      }
    }();

    var items1 = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'rozp'];
    items1.forEach(each);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("REQUEST FINISH","STATUS", 30);
  }

  catch(err){
 throw err;
  }
}

function go(ss, tabl, statusFin) {
ss.getSheetByName(tabl).getRange("B2").setValue(statusFin);}
```

Можна написать функцию для каждого листа:

```
function Fin_Sheet1() {
   ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").setValue(statusFin);}
```

Но хочется разобраться с кодом который выше. Что я упустил?

Comment: Было бы здорово посмотреть пример данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант

```
"use strict";

function onEdit(е) {
  try{
    var statusIn = "REQUEST IN PROCESS";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

    var eacher = function(){
      return function(name){
        action(ss, name, statusIn);
      }
    }();

    var items = ['Sheet1', 'rozp'];
    items.forEach(eacher);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('DONE');
  } catch(err){
    throw err;
  }
}

function action(ss, name, statusIn) {
  var senr = ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B2").getValue();
  var rasar = senr.length;
  var bar_rr = ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B5").getValue();
  var rer = bar_rr.length;
  var bar_r1r = ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("F5").getValue();
  var re1r = bar_r1r.length;
  var bar_r2r = ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("J5").getValue();
  var re2r = bar_r2r.length;
  var bar_r3r = ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("N5").getValue();
  var re3r = bar_r3r.length;
  if (rer > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }
  if (re1r > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }
  if (re2r > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }
  if (re3r > rasar) {
    ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }
}
```

Теперь можно контролировать список имен листов. Например, `var items = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'rozp'];` и обратиться к логике функции `action`.

Comment: Можно ли функцию:    
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('DONE');
Показывать в определёных листах или во всех листах одновременно?

Comment: @TapaTip, этот метод срабатывает для текущей открытой в браузере Таблицы. Я бы не рекомендовал добавлять тосты вовремя исполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то ваш скрипт надо просто ограничить выполнением на активном листе.
У вас первая группа команд как раз обрабатывает активный лист, а после комментария

> // Следующий лист

Вы зачем-то пишете туже самую обработку, но уже перейдя в скрипте на другой лист.
Далее:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sen = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange("B2").getValue();
```

Вы уже в ss "перешли" на активный лист, а потом снова обращаетесь по имени.
Соответственно при разных именах листов - нужно подставлять свои имена. 
Попробуйте во всех следующих командах обращаться к нему, без имени, например:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sen = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
```

У вас 4 проверки, но результат записывается в одну и ту же ячейку. Все это можно переписать как:

```
  if ((re > rasa) || (re2 > rasa) || (re1 > rasa) || (re3 > rasa) {
    ss.getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }
```

Тогда весь ваш код, если не ошибаюсь, должен выглядеть вот так:

```
function onEdit(е) {
  var statusIn = "REQUEST IN PROCESS";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sen = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var rasa = sen.length;
  var bar_r1 = ss.getRange("F5").getValue();
  var re1 = bar_r1.length;
  var bar_r = ss.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var re = bar_r.length;
  var bar_r2 = ss.getRange("J5").getValue();
  var re2 = bar_r2.length;
  var bar_r3 = ss.getRange("N5").getValue();
  var re3 = bar_r3.length;
  if ((re > rasa) || (re2 > rasa) || (re1 > rasa) || (re3 > rasa) {
    ss.getRange("B2").setValue(statusIn);
  }
}
```

И тогда на каком листе нажмете - на том и сработает